# Proof of inverse inequality for polynomials

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, finite-element-method

In my FEM lecture notes we make in several theorems use of the so called **invers inequality for polynomials**:

> Let $\omega\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ and let $p_h\in
>  \mathbb{P}^k(\omega,\mathbb{R})$ a polynomial of order $k$ defined on
> $\omega$, then the following inverse inequality holds: \begin{align}
>  ||p_h||_{L^2{(\partial\omega)}}\leq C \frac{k}{\sqrt{diam(\omega)}}||p_h||_{L^2{(\omega)}}
>  \end{align} where $C$ is a positiv constant that dosent depend on the
> size of $\omega$.

I would like to know how to show this result.

Comment: Can you define the norms?

Comment: Both are the standard $L^2$ norm. I have added this to the question.

Comment: Just a thought: Take the finite dimensional space of all polynomials of degree $\leq k$. Use the fact that any two norms on this space are equivalent. That will give you a constant that depends on $\omega$. If you replace $\omega$ by $r\omega$ (the dilation), then the constant would change by the change of variables formula. Examining how it changes would be instructive.